# insert values from one table to another talbe

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to insert all `id` from `tbl1` to `tbl2` and their deserved datetime (which is same for all of them)

I've tried this:

```
insert into Tbl2(UserId, TimesTamp)
values (select u.Id from tbl1 as u, N'2016-01-31 23:59:59')
```

but it doesn't work.

tbl2 looks like this:

> ID | UserId | TimesTamp

and ID is auto increment of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid syntax `INSERT INTO SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO Tbl2(UserId, TimesTamp)
SELECT u.Id,'2016-01-31 23:59:59'
FROM tbl1 AS u;
```

Remarks:

- `Timestamp` should be quoted with `[]` if SQL Server  ([reserved/future keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx))
- date literal should be in [ISO-8601](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) (`'2016-01-31T23:59:59'`) to avoid problems with lang/dateformat settings